# "not authorized to perform operation" message in Xfce remote desktop

Tags: performance, xfce, remote-desktop

On ubuntu 14.04 i installed Xfce to maker remote desktop working. when i rdp to the machine and while performing some tasks like mounting removable usb media I get "not authorized to perform operation" message. I got this message when i tried to change some other settings like desktop settings, network settings, etc.
This problem has almost made remoted desktop feature useless for me. I couldn't perform any administrative task remotely.